# How to pass Xml data as a parameter to a Test in mbunit v3

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mbunit, gallio

I was reading about data driven testing using mbunit from this article.
http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/04/mbunit-datafixture-data-driven-unit.html
I am using v3 of mbunit now and the attributes used for DataDriven testing are Not applicable in V3 as per the release notes for V3.  Using this article http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2009/03/announcing-gallio-and-mbunit-v306.html, I was able to do Data Driven testing using xml data source. But I have to use [Bind("price")] with each parameter. In V2, there was a way to specify the datatype of a class, deserialized to contain the xml data, in the ForEachTest attribute. And doing so we can just pass the object of the class to the test method as a parameter. Is there any way to do such thing in v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in [Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org/) [v3.2](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=release_notes:v3.2) yet. You must bind each single parameter with the `[Bind]` attribute.

It's a excellent idea however; and an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=690) was created accordingly. It should make v3.3.